# Angular export html

Tags: html, angular, export

Whats up! I have a question - maybe banal, maybe not. I need to remove the HTML code to a file after generating it in the component. And everything would be cool, if not for the fact that if I do it

```
document.getElementById ('summary').outerHTML
```

or

```
this.summaryReport.nativeElement.innerHTML
```

I`ve

```
 @ViewChild('summaryReport') summaryReport: ElementRef;
```

html:

```
 <div #summaryReport id="summary" class="summary">
        <div class="row border border-secondary">
            <div class="col-md">
                <h2> Podsumowanie sprzedaży biletów </h2>
            </div>
        </div>          
            <div class="row">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let d of sortedData |keyvalue">
                    <div class="row">{{d.key}}</div>
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <th>{{'Ticket name'|translate}}</th>
                            <th>{{'Price'|translate }}</th>
                            <th>{{'Quantity'|translate}}</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let el of d.value">
                                <td>{{el.ticketName}}</td>
                                <td>{{el.price / 100}}</td>
                                <td>{{el.quantity}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in the verse I get 'bindings = {}' in place of ngFor.
Can anyone tell me what I do not understand?: D

Comment: you need to remove and show HTML code You can use `ngIf` Directives.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve answer.
Time....

I'm trying to generate a variable too quickly. After added another method to send html , work fine